# Datatype to store accumulated scores for multiple players

Tags: python-3.x

I have problem here. I'm new in Python. I want to creat a mini game name dice roll. The rule is like this:

1. Number of rolls is unlimited
2. Number of players is unlimited
   (unlimited means that user can add as many players and rolls as they want)
3. Then after certain attempts for each player, it will compute the total dice from how many times they make a roll
4. Then the program will compute which player has the highest total and becomes the winner.

This is my code and I'm currently stuck at point 4.

```
import random

numPlayer = int(input("Enter number of player:"))
numTest = int(input("Enter the number of test:"))

def dice_roll():
    total = 0
    for i in range(numTest):
        nana = random.randint(1 , 6)
        total = total + nana
    #print("TOTAL: " + str(total))
    return total

player = 0
for j in range(numPlayer):  # number of player
    print("\n")
    print("Player " + str(j + 1))
    print("-------")
    print(dice_roll())

# create a variable to store total for each player
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python we have a data type called a dictionary that stores key/value pairs like name/score that is perfect for your program. I added a dictionary called highScore to your code and it works great now and prints the (score, player) pair so you know who won and what their score was. It still prints the other players too so you can check it:

```
import random


def dice_roll(rolls):
    total = 0
    for i in range(rolls):
        nana = random.randint(1, 6)
        total = total + nana
    print("TOTAL :" + str(total))
    return total


# gather user parameters
numPlayer = int(input("Enter number of player:"))
numTest = int(input("Enter the number of test:"))

# initialize a dictionary to store the scores by player name
highScore = {}

player = 0
for j in range(numPlayer):
    print("\n")
    name = ("Player "+str(j+1))  # assign the name to a string variable
    print(name)
    print("-------")
    score = dice_roll(numTest)   # store the value in an int variable
    print(str(score))
    highScore[name] = score      # store the name and score in a dictionary

# prints the high score and the player (score, player)
print(max(zip(highScore.values(), highScore.keys())))
```

I hope this helps. The max zip will sort by value and print both the value and the key of the max value.

Comment: I put the name and score into variables and then printed those variables to keep your current formatting. It's a little easier to ready this way.